# What is the (model independent) density of baryons in the Universe?

Tags: cosmology, baryons

I know that Planck has measured the baryon density, $\Omega_B$, as a fraction of the critical density, $\rho_{CRIT}$.  Is there a measurement of baryon density that's independent of the critical mass and the $\lambda CDM$ model that one can use as a sanity check?

Comment: Sanity check against LCDM??? You must be insane!!! +1 As with any failing model or theory, LCDM supporters are very aggressive and will downvote you for any doubt.

Comment: @safesphere - Yes, I've noticed that.  People who don't understand the first thing about differential geometry seem to have some very religious views of GR.

Comment: I think it doesn't exist. LCDM is a six parameter model with $\Omega_B$ being one of them. Indeed, the baryons density can be measured with other cosmological models but it would be still a model-dependent parameter.

Comment: @NimaRonaghi - You are correct.  This is a free parameter in the model.  The current value is selected so that the baryon to photon ratio makes BBN give the right answer.